# I want an input with a hidden digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, passwords

Could it be possible to have those conditions in my input ?:

1- Allow only **digits** to be entered.

2- Those digits be hidden like a password.

3- The numeric keyboard to pop-up on mobile browsers and not the general keyboard.

4- All this want to be cross-browser compatible.

```
<input type="number" name="pin-code">
```

Comment: Would it be possible with a javascript ?

Comment: absolutely @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Okay, you'll want to put that into the question (use the "edit" link). Fairly certain there is no *simple* answer.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 5):

[image]You can try this one `<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">`

```
input[type=number] {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

[Please see this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswathyb950/ss9dvuyn/)

Comment: Did anyone even test it before upvoting?

Comment: [`input` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) have no `inputmode` attribute.

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work because i haven't the digit keyboard !, and I said it in the question !

Comment: Sorry for the first one, I have updated my answer. This one is working.

Comment: `type="number"` and `pattern="[0-9]*"` don't go together.

Comment: where i put this code `input[type=number] {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}`

Comment: @prince: It's CSS.

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle in the answer

Comment: Well, that's great for webkit browsers. Wha about the more than half the browsing population who aren't?

Comment: @AswathyBalan It works like charm in your fiddle link. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @anusreemn: Uh huh, except on Firefox. Except on IE. Except on Edge. And apparently (see prince's comment above), except on Chrome Mobile. Nice of you to show up and support your friend, but...

Comment: In your fiddle it doesn't work because the digits are not hidden ! look my update question please.

Comment: @prince I have tested this in my  chrome mobile. The following conditions are working. please find the screenshot above.

1- Allow only digits to be entered.

2- Those digits be hidden like a password.

3- The numeric keyboard to pop-up on mobile browsers and not the general keyboard.

Comment: it's not compatible with all browsers, firefox android for exemple